# Solving graph theory problems using neural networks

Tags: graph-theory

It's known that many problems (e.g. XOR) have the exact solutions represented by neural networks. The question is: *What kind of graph theory problems can be solved using neural networks*?

Comment: Maybe neural networks can help shed a light on Hadwiger's conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that has found a real-world application, in the context of [quantum error correction:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction) The decoding of [stabilizer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code) is a problem of minimum weight-perfect matching on a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) (for the surface code or [toric code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code)) or a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) (for the [color code](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/quantum-error-correction-surface-code-vs-color-code)). [Recurrent neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) offer a performance that is comparable or better than existing algorithms. Some pointers to the literature:

- [A neural decoder for
  topological codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04238)
- [Decoding small surface codes
  with feedforward neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00857)
- [Machine-learning-assisted correction of correlated qubit errors in a topological code](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07855)
- [Deep neural
  network probabilistic decoder for stabilizer codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09334)